# How to set the percentage of inference calls when performing A/B testing using AWS sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

I'm new to sagemaker. I'm trying to figure out how to perform A/B testing using AWS sagemaker. I understand setting the train_instance_count will distribute the training across two instances. But how do I specify the set the percentage of inference calls each model will handle and perform A/B testing? 
This is all I could find from the docs

> "Amazon SageMaker can also manage model A/B testing for you. You can
>   configure the endpoint to spread traffic across as many as five
>   different models and set the percentage of inference calls you want
>   each one to handle. You can change all of this on the fly, giving you
>   a lot of flexibility to run experiments and determine which model
>   produces the most accurate results in the real world."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have multiple Production Variants behind an Amazon SageMaker endpoint. Each production variant has an initial variant weight and based on the ratio of each variant weight to the total sum of weights, SageMaker can distribute the calls to each of the models. For example, if you have only one production variant with a weight of 1, all traffic will go to this variant. If you add another production variant with an initial weight of 2, the new variant will get 2/3 of the traffic and the first variant will get 1/3.

You can see more details on ProductionVariant on Amazon SageMaker documentations here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_ProductionVariant.html

You can provide an array of ProductionVariants when you "Create Endpoint Configuration": https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_CreateEndpointConfig.html , and you can update the variants with "Update Endpoint Weights and Capacities" call: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_UpdateEndpointWeightsAndCapacities.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this, I have just created a function that implements the AWS SDK library with some user inputs. The example splits the traffic in the ratio 1:1 for model1 and model2, based on the InitialVariantWeight parameter in the code below. Details on the SageMaker libraries are available here: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html

```
def custom_create_endpoint_config(model1,model2,endpoint_config_name,instancetype= 'm1.t2.medium'):
    response = client.create_endpoint_config(
    EndpointConfigName=endpoint_config_name,
    ProductionVariants= [
    {
        'VariantName': 'variant1',
        'ModelName': model1,
        'InitialInstanceCount': 1,
        'InstanceType': instancetype,
        'InitialVariantWeight': 1
    },
    {
        'VariantName': 'variant2',
        'ModelName': model2,
        'InitialInstanceCount': 1,
        'InstanceType': instancetype,
        'InitialVariantWeight': 1
    },],        
    Tags=[
    {
        'Key': str(endpoint_config_name +'_key'),
        'Value': str(endpoint_config_value +'_value')
    },]
    )


def custom_delete_endpoint_config(endpoint_config_name):
    client.delete_endpoint_config(\
        EndpointConfigName=config_name)
```